# my_hash.keys == [], yet my_hash[key] gives a value?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to demonstrate a situation where it's necessary to pass a block to `Hash.new` in order to set up default values for a given key when creating a hash of hashes.

To show what can go *wrong*, I've created the following code, which passes a single value as an *argument* to `Hash.new`. I expected all outer hash keys to wind up holding a reference to the same inner hash, causing the counts for the "piles" to get mixed together. And indeed, that does seem to have happened. But `part_counts.each` doesn't seem to find any keys/values to iterate over, and `part_counts.keys` returns an empty array. Only `part_counts[0]` and `part_counts[1]` successfully retrieve a value for me.

```
piles = [
  [:gear, :spring, :gear],
  [:axle, :gear, :spring],
]

# I do realize this should be:
#   Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(0)}
part_counts = Hash.new(Hash.new(0))

piles.each_with_index do |pile, pile_index|
  pile.each do |part|
    part_counts[pile_index][part] += 1
  end
end

p part_counts # => {}
p part_counts.keys # => []
# The next line prints no output
part_counts.each { |key, value| p key, value }
p part_counts[0] # => {:gear=>3, :spring=>2, :axle=>1}
```

For context, here is the corrected code that I intend to show after the "broken" code. The parts for each pile within `part_counts` are separated, as they should be. `each` and `keys` work as expected, as well.

```
# ...same pile initialization code as above...
part_counts = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(0)}
# ...same part counting code as above...
p part_counts # => {0=>{:gear=>2, :spring=>1}, 1=>{:axle=>1, :gear=>1, :spring=>1}}
p part_counts.keys # => [0, 1]
# The next line of code prints:
# 0
# {:gear=>2, :spring=>1}
# 1
# {:axle=>1, :gear=>1, :spring=>1}
part_counts.each { |key, value| p key, value }
p part_counts[0] # => {:gear=>2, :spring=>1}
```

But why don't `each` and `keys` work (at all) in the first sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll start by decomposing this a little bit:

```
part_counts = Hash.new(Hash.new(0))
```

That's the same as saying:

```
default_hash = { }
default_hash.default = 0
part_counts = { }
part_counts.default = default_hash
```

Later on, you're saying things like this:

```
part_counts[pile_index][part] += 1
```

That's the same as saying:

```
h = part_counts[pile_index]
h[part] += 1
```

You're not using the (correct) block form of the default value for your Hash so accessing the default value doesn't auto-vivify the key. That means that `part_counts[pile_index]` doesn't create a `pile_index` key in `part_counts`, it just gives you `part_counts.default` and you're really saying:

```
h = part_counts.default
h[part] += 1
```

You're not doing anything else to add keys to `part_counts` so it has no keys and:

```
part_counts.keys == [ ]
```

So why does `part_counts[0]` give us `{:gear=>3, :spring=>2, :axle=>1}`? `part_counts` doesn't have any keys and in particular doesn't have a `0` key so:

```
part_counts[0]
```

is the same as

```
part_counts.default
```

Up above where you're accessing `part_counts[pile_index]`, you're really just getting a reference to the default, the Hash won't clone it, you get the whole default value that the Hash will use next time. That means that:

```
part_counts[pile_index][part] += 1
```

is another way of saying:

```
part_counts.default[part] += 1
```

so you're actually just changing `part_counts`'s default value in-place. Then when you `part_counts[0]`, you're accessing this modified default value and there's the `{:gear=>3, :spring=>2, :axle=>1}` that you accidentally built in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

The value given to `Hash.new` is used as the default value, but this value is not inserted into the hash. So `part_count` remains empty. You can get the default value by using `part_count[...]` but this has no effect on the hash, it doesn't really contain the key.

When you call `part_counts[pile_index][part] += 1`, then `part_counts[pile_index]` returns the default value, and it's this value that is modified with the assignment, not `part_counts`.

You have something like:

```
outer = Hash.new({})
outer[1][2] = 3
p outer, outer[1]
```

which can also be written like:

```
inner = {}
outer = Hash.new(inner)

inner2 = outer[1] # inner2 refers to the same object as inner, outer is not modified
inner2[2] = 3 # same as inner[2] = 3

p outer, inner
```